# Is it possible to use json files as templates in Azure Data Factory through .Net SDK?

Tags: .net, azure, sdk, azure-data-factory, jsontemplate

I am using .Net SDK for creating the pipelines and its Datasets, Linked services. I am having a doubt that we can get values from JSON templates and pass those values to the built-in methods. The following Class is used to create Azure Storage Linked Service.

```
    client.LinkedServices.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName,
                new LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateParameters()
                {
                    LinkedService = new LinkedService()
                    {
                        Name = "AzureStorageLinkedService",
                        Properties = new LinkedServiceProperties
                        (
                            new AzureStorageLinkedService("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=**StorageName**;AccountKey=**StorageKey**")
                        )
                    }
                }
            );
```

I have to get the values for Name and Properties from the JSON Template and pass those values to **LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateParameters** Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you could use [LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateWithRawJsonContentParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactories.models.linkedservicecreateorupdatewithrawjsoncontentparameters?view=azuremgmtdatafactories-4.12.1) instead of the  LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateParameters .

LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateWithRawJsonContentParameters has content property which could set the json template parameters.

More details, you could refer to this example.

Json file:

```
{
    "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "description": "",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": " "      }
    }
}
```

Net code:

```
LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateWithRawJsonContentParameters d1 =  new LinkedServiceCreateOrUpdateWithRawJsonContentParameters();

string path = @"D:\json2.txt";

using (StreamReader s1 = new StreamReader(path))
{

    d1.Content = s1.ReadToEnd();
}


Console.WriteLine("Creating Azure Storage linked service");

client.LinkedServices.BeginCreateOrUpdateWithRawJsonContent(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName,"linkservicename", d1);
```

Result:

[image]